# Modifying value of object within foreach loop

Tags: c#, xna, foreach

I defined a list of rectangles called enemies, and I'm trying to move through the rectangles in the list and decrement their X value, but I am getting an error "cannot modify 'i' because it is a foreach iteration variable."  I'm wondering what is wrong with this and if there is a correct way of going about it.

```
        foreach (Rectangle i in enemies)
        {

            i.X --:

        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using an evil mutable struct.  Don't.

Comment: What do you have against Rectangles that make them enemies? :/ More to the point, is this the System.Drawing.Rectangle struct, is it a custom struct of yours, or _____?

Comment: I figured you're referring to an XNA `Rectange` (which is a Struct) as opposed to the WPF Rectangle class, so I added xna as a tag.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: "What do you have against Rectangles that make them enemies?" -- That made me laugh a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Value types are copied *by value*; that's why they're called "value types". When you do this, you are making a *copy* of the rectangle and then mutating *the copy*. Now, it just so happens that the foreach loop makes an *immutable copy* of the value and tells you that you cannot change it, which is good, because it just caught your bug. Had you been making that change to a mutable copy you might not have found the bug for a long time.

Your Enemy type should probably be a reference type, not a value type. Have the enemy *contain* a rectangle, not *be* a rectangle.  You can then mutate the rectangle in the reference to the enemy.

Comment: While I agree that Enemy should possibly a reference type, there is one small caveat when it comes to XNA: If you want to run on the Xbox 360, the garbage collector is a big issue, which is why mutable structs are somewhat more common there. Trying to make a game with many enemies (e.g., Geometry Wars) could be a performance challenge (although I'd assume Object Pooling makes much more sense than mutable structs).

Comment: @MichaelStum: Keep in mind that I took a guess that the original poster was using XNA, so I added that tag. It makes sense because in XNA Rectangle is a struct, but there is still a tiny chance the OP was using another struct Rectangle? Maybe...

Comment: Nope, you were correct in assuming it was XNA :) thanks for the help all, I just recently started using it.